# Resolving dependencies for component registered in a different project with autofac

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, resolve, clean-architecture

So I have an Infrastructure Layer (Project1) where I register all modules, so I am using Autofac and it goes like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyConcreteClass>().As<IMyInterface>()
                .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(string), "myParameter1"))
                .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(string), "myParameter2"));
```

In another project (Project2), I have a service I will call MyService which invokes MyConcreteClass and I intend to resolve it, but unsure how. First of all, the appsettings are found in this second project, and it being a dotnet core project, I know I can easily get the appsettings by injecting IConfiguration in this MyService and then something like: `var myParam1 = Configuration["UsefulSettings:MyParameter1"]`

Two questions:

1. Should I resolve the param for the c-tor of MyConcreteClass inside Project1, where I registered MyConcreteClass as being the implementation of IMyInterface (so basically, I am asking if I should register and resolve at the same time)? If so, how do I do this, considering the params are found in Project2 appsettings?
2. If I can resolve MyConcreteClass in Project2 (after registering it in Project1), how is this done?
   In Autofac docs, I notice they use something like (https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/parameters.html):

`var service = scope.Resolve<IMyInterface>()`

`.WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(string), Configuration["UsefulSettings:MyParameter1"]))`

`.WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(string), Configuration["UsefulSettings:MyParameter2"])));`

...but who is **scope**?

So, which approach is better, 1 or 2, and could you help fill in the gaps please?

Thank you.

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here - some things that aren't clear, possibly due to language used, and some gaps in missing information. A good question [should have a minimal reproduction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help communicate. Also, unfortunately language precision in these situations is key - "a service ...MyService which invokes MyConcreteClass" for example: Is MyService _a class_ or is it something else? What does "invokes MyConcreteClass" mean - it's a dependency? [Update the question itself to contain the info; don't respond in comments/]

Comment: Since you tagged this question as "clean-architecture", where is your Project2 located? Is it in the "Application" layer (UseCase calls service interfaces) ?